# Python: how to compress lists to a zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, gzip

please help, since i am new to python..

i am trying to fetch lists based on a match and writing them to separate compressed gz files, as per gzip module [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html). But i am getting `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Not sure what mistake i am doing here.

`Python code`

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import gzip

X = ['apple,banana,fruits,orange', 'dog,cat,animals,horse', 'mouse,elephant,animals,peacock']
filter = ('fruits', 'animals')

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in X:
    for f in filter:
        if re.search(fr'\b{f}\b', x):
            d[f].append(x)

for k, v in d.items():
    with gzip.open(f'{k}.csv.gz', 'wb') as fi:
        for y in v:
            fi.write(y)
```

from lists in X, it matches `filter` (fruits, animals) and writes separate csv files if replace gzip.open to just open. 
But i want to write them in compressed gz format and using above example as found in gzip document.

```
with open(f'{k}.csv', 'w') as fi: #It works fine for writing into csv file. (thanks to Austin)
with gzip.open(f'{k}.csv.gz', 'wb') as fi: # Gives below error.
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Maria\Documents\drs\stopper.py", line 17, in <module>
    fi.write(y)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 260, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

`Expected Output:`

```
zcat fruits.csv.gz
apple,banana,fruits,orange

zcat animals.csv.gz
mouse,elephant,animals,peacock
mouse,elephant,animals,peacock
```

Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to convert your strings to bytes: `fi.write(y.encode())`.

Comment: OMG.. It works.. i have been struggling since 5hours for this.. Thanks a lot Ben

Comment: Really appreciate your immediate response.. Please move it to answer section, So i will mark it as resolved..THANKS Again.

Comment: Putting `gzip +"a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"` into a search engine gives you multiple relevant results, including the one I'm using to mark this a duplicate. The plus and quotes are important because we care about this exact message.